# how to make the biplot name more clear using ggbiplot

Tags: r, plot, ggbiplot

I have a data which can be download from here 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5f1135e4f750a39b0255

I try to plot a PCA with ggbiplot using the following function

```
data <- read.delim("path to the data.txt")
data.pca <- prcomp (data, center = TRUE, scale =TRUE)
library(ggbiplot)
g <- ggbiplot(data.pca, obs.scale =1, var.scale=1, ellipse = TRUE, circle=TRUE)
g <- g + scale_color_discrete(name='')
g <- g + theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', legend.position = 'top')
print(g)
```

however, it is very difficult to see the biplot lines names,

is there any way to make it more clear or show it better ?

Comment: `varname.size =5, varname.adjust =5` helps a wee bit

Comment: @user20650 I have tried to use the varname.size=3, varname.adjust=5 but it is still not clear enough. I am more searching for a way to be able to publish. but the quality is very low and I dot know what I should do to make it more clear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a way to make it clearer is to adjust the size and position of the labels using the `varname.size`and `varname.adjust` arguments. However, with a lot of variables it still looks crowded. By increasing the length of the arrows (similar to `stats::biplot()`), makes it look somewhat better (imo)

```
# install ggbiplot
#require(devtools)
#install_github('ggbiplot','vqv')

library(httr) 
library(ggbiplot)

# read data
url <- "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/5f1135e4f750a39b0255/raw/data.txt"
dat <- read.table(text=content(GET(url), as="text"), header=TRUE)

# pca 
data.pca <- prcomp (dat, center = TRUE, scale =TRUE)

# original plot + increase labels size and space from line
p <- ggbiplot(data.pca, obs.scale=1, 
              var.scale=1, circle=F, 
              varname.size=4, varname.adjust=2)  
p
```

[image]

```
# use coord_equal() to change size ratio of plot (excludes use of circle)
p <- p + coord_equal(1.5) + theme_classic()
p
```

[image]

To extend the arrows, the x and y coordinates need to be recalculated. You can then use these to edit the relevant grobs, and change any other parameter (colour, size, rotation etc). (you could go the whole `ggplotGrob(p)` approach, but just use `grid.edit()` below.)

```
# function to rescale the x & y positions of the lines and labels
f <- function(a0, a1, M=M)
      {
      l <- lapply(as.list(environment()), as.numeric)
      out <- M* (l$a1 - l$a0) + l$a0
      grid::unit(out, "native")
      }  

# get list of grobs in current graphics window
grobs <- grid.ls(print=FALSE)  

# find segments grob for the arrows
s_id <- grobs$name[grep("segments", grobs$name)]

# edit length and colour of lines
seg <- grid.get(gPath(s_id[2]))     
grid.edit(gPath(s_id[2]),  
            x1=f(seg$x0, seg$x1, 2), 
            y1=f(seg$y0, seg$y1, 2),
            gp=gpar(col="red"))


# find text grob for the arrow labels
lab_id <- grobs$name[grep("text", grobs$name)]

# edit position of text, and rotate and colour labels
seg2 <- grid.get(gPath(lab_id)) 
grid.edit(gPath(lab_id),  
            x=f(seg$x0, seg2$x, 2), 
            y=f(seg$y0, seg2$y, 2),
            rot=0,
            gp=gpar(col="red"))
```

[image]

Subjective if this makes it  better, and perhaps it is easier just to use `biplot()` or even define a new function

Comment: thanks for your effort, 'I liked and accept your answer